# CustomGridview with FrameLayout problems

Tags: android, gridview, android-framelayout

i had created a custom gridview and here is my custom_gridview.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/shadowText"
        android:id="@+id/textViewGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="test" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.manhtuan.bai2xemanh.MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The gridview will show like this :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR8o6.png)

I want to make every image show in square shape , so i set Framelayout with both witdh and height 125dp above, but it not work , help me i'm beginer :(

Comment: can you post custom_gridview.xml code too

Comment: above is custom_gridview.xml code, do you mean activity_main.xml ?

Comment: how are you putting in 3*3 grid shown in image?

Comment: It 's `android:numColumns` at activity_main .Sorry i'm just edited put activity_main.xml code above. But it just set column number, didn't set row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happing due to image size.  `FrameLayout` is taking hight from `ImageView`. Set `ImageView` hight to same as  `FrameLayout` like below -

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="125dp"
             android:layout_height="125dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewGrid"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textViewGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="test"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you,it work !! I though `ImageView`match_parent will match with length of FrameLayout :p